# How do I skip an RSS item if field empty?

Tags: php, xpath, rss, domdocument

Another little thing has been driving me crazy... I want to pull in an RSS feed and display it using PHP. It asks for the mrss decription (because it doesn't have all the extra junk attached to it). The only problem is that the feed has advertisements. So when the script calls for the media description of an advertisement (for which there is none), the whole page fails.

I've tried using continue and an if...else based on length, but it's still not working..

```
$xml=("http://feeds.abcnews.com/abcnews/gmavideos");
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);
$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');

for ($i=0; $i<=10; $i++)
  {
  $item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $item_link=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.pheedo.com/namespace/pheedo', 'origLink')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $item_desc=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/', 'description')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

    if ($x->length == 0) {
        exit('etc.');
    }
    else {
  echo ("<p><a href='" . $item_link
  . "' target='_blank'>" . $item_title . "</a>");
  echo ("<br />");
  echo ($item_desc . "</p>");
  }
  }
```

Any guidance appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing the error message I can't know for sure, but most likely the script is failing because of this line:

```
$item_desc=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/', 'description')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

If there is no description element, then `getElementsByTagNameNS()` will return an empty `DOMNodeList`, so the `->item(0)->childNodes` will fail.

You need to separate these out.

```
$item_desc_nodes = $x->item($i)->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/', 'description');
if ($item_desc_nodes->length) {
    $item_desc = $item_desc_nodes->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
} else {
    continue;
}
```

Honestly, though, you should really be using XPath instead of `getElementsByTagNameNS`.

You should also use `->textContent` instead of `->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue`.

**UPDATE:** This is how I would accomplish the same task using XPath

```
$xml = 'http://feeds.abcnews.com/abcnews/gmavideos';
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($xmlDoc);
$xpath->registerNamespace('media', 'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
$xpath->registerNamespace('pheedo', 'http://www.pheedo.com/namespace/pheedo');

// filter out the ads in the xpath expression itself by saying there must be
// a pheedo:origLink element in the item
$items = $xpath->query('/rss/channel/item[pheedo:origLink][position() < 11]');

$linktmpl = '<p><a href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a><br />%s</p>'."\n";

foreach($items as $item) {
    $item_title = $xpath->evaluate('string(title)', $item);
    $item_link = $xpath->evaluate('string(pheedo:origLink)', $item);
    $item_desc = $xpath->evaluate('string(media:description)', $item);

    $escaped = array_map('htmlspecialchars', array($item_link, $item_title, $item_desc));
    vprintf($linktmpl, $escaped);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($item_title=="") continue;
```

Comment: This isn't helpful. PHP will completely error-out before `$item_title` is assigned because of the OP's chaining without checking that the `DOMNodeList` has any items.

Comment: uh.. no it won't. You need to use it in your scope smart one.

Comment: If you run the OP's code, you get this error when the loop reaches an "advertisement" item: `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function item() on a non-object in rss_item_test.php on line 12`. So there's never a blank `$item_title` to test--it hasn't been assigned because the right-hand side hasn't finished evaluating before it hits fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

> The only problem is that the feed has advertisements. So when the
>   script calls for the media description of an advertisement (for which
>   there is none), the whole page fails.

**Use**:

```
/*/channel/item[media:description]
```

**Or, alternatively**:

```
/*/channel/item[not(title='Advertisement:')]
```

I personally would use and recommend the first expression above.